# Flex 4: Sparks text fields are not using the default font and giving warnings

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flex4, migration

I get the following warning when I run my application:

> warning: incompatible embedded font
>   'Arial' specified for
>   spark.components::Label (Label104) .
>   This component requires that the
>   embedded font be declared with
>   embedAsCff=true.

The application I am working on is a mix of Halo and Sparks components as I am migrating it to Flex 4. The text that is showing in the text fields is defaulting the systems serif font.

There are a few problems with this warning.

1) I am not embedding any fonts in the application. I am not even assigning the Arial font to any of the components.

2) If I check the "Use Flash Text Engine in MX components", then all the text fields in the app throw the warning. Not just the sparks text fields.

Why does flex 4 think that I am using an embedded font with the sparks components? Is there any way to get around this warning and have the text fields use a non embedded font?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the [FlexWiz blog ran into this issue as well](http://flexwiz.amosl.com/flex/flex4/flex-4-migration-tips/).

> **Embedded fonts problems**
>
> Now that my project compiles and runs,
>   I notice that the fonts don’t look
>   right. However, this time the nice
>   folks at Adobe provided us with the
>   following warning:
>
> *warning: incompatible embedded font
>   'ArialFont' specified for
>   mx.controls::UITextField
>   (UITextField36). This component
>   requires that the embedded font be
>   declared with embedAsCff=false.*
>
> Well, as it turns out, the new SDK now
>   assigns two different types of
>   embedded fonts: CFF embedded and
>   non-CFF embedded. The CFF is used
>   exclusively by spark components, while
>   the mx components can only use non-CFF
>   – too bad, since it practically means
>   you cannot share styles between, say,
>   spark and halo labels and text fields
>   like I did.
>
> To fix this, you’d have to define each
>   of your embedded fonts twice: one
>   instance for spark, and another
>   instance for halo..  oops, I mean mx.
>   In the mx font embed, set embedAsCFF
>   to ’false’, and then create styles for
>   both types and use them from their
>   corresponding components. There is a
>   [detailed explanation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f5f.html) with code samples
>   on the [Adobe web site](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f5f.html).

Comment: I understand how to create the embedded fonts for both types of components. However, I am not embedding any fonts within my application and I am still getting this warning. I found a hack fix by setting the default font to all my sparks components to "_sans". If i do not specify the text controls to use the device fonts then I get the embed warning and it puts in an ugly font into the control.